# Can I use Qt Creator to create a console application?

Tags: c++, c, qt, user-interface

I'm looking for the best IDE for `C++` and found `Qt` is the best approach anyway.
Can I use `Qt Creator` as an IDE for `C++`? Obviously this is my learning time and would learn to create GUIs and user interfaces with `C++` in future.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can. You can create plain C++ projects.

Comment: Can i use for `Console programs` too as a learner?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what you are doing. C++ doesn't have a standard GUI toolkit anyway.

Comment: Qt Creator is a general-purpose IDE. I use it even on pure C embedded projects where the platform itself doesn't even support C++ (it doesn't even have a C++ compiler). So, not only you can create console applications, you can use it to develop for almost any target that's supported by qmake or cmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can. Here below I show you the screenshot of QtCreator's "New project" form:

[image: QtCreator "New project" form]

As you can see you can easily select to create a standard "C++" project (making use of `qmake`) or also a standard "C++" project (making use of `cmake`).

Your plain C++ project can be a simple console application (making use of `cin` and `cout` for example).